# I have made a program executable, I have added it's dir to path. It still wont execute. What gives?

Tags: path

I have tried:

```
gaspipe@kali:~/bashscripts$ ls
./  ../  addpath*  autoinstaller

gaspipe@kali:~/bashscripts$ cd ..

gaspipe@kali:~$ addpath
addpath: command not found

gaspipe@kali:~$ addpath*
addpath*: command not found

gaspipe@kali:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games/home/gaspipe/bashscripts
```

The problem I have with the `PATH` environment variable man, nothing has been more difficult for me in Linux and it is such a simple concept. Yet just having a script made that adds a directory to the path has been such a battle for me.
I do not want to keep opening the `~/.bashrc` file and typing long path names. I just want to type `addpath <dir>` and have this work.

Why is this not a program that has been made?

Comment: What is your user home directory? Because this is not usual: `/usr/games/home/gaspipe/...` (having your home directory under `/usr/games` should not be the correct). Try `echo $HOME`.

Comment: Do you really want to add to the PATH or do you want to just execute the script? If you have a lot of scripts in the directory then you'll want to add it to the PATH. On the other hand if you want to execute your script then you can invoke it using the full path. For example `./myscript`. Note that `./` is the path to the current directory. If your script is in `~/test`, you can invoke it with `~/test/myscript`.., You

Comment: The prompt suggests that you're using kali linux. That is for experiences people, and not meant for everyday use. This question suggests that you're not experienced, and tasks like that more often comes up in everyday use. If you really need the tools that kali is somewhat famous for you can install them on most other distributions.

Answer (score 3):

Your local folder isn't delimited from the /usr/games directory:

```
gaspipe@kali:~$ echo $PATH
...:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games/home/gaspipe/bashscripts
```

It should be:

```
gaspipe@kali:~$ echo $PATH
...:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/gaspipe/bashscripts
```

(I cut the start of the PATH to make the difference more visible).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a script to manipulate the environment of the current shell, you'll have to source the script:

```
source ./addpath
```

or

```
. ./addpath
```

Alternatively, you could make your `addpath` a shell function or alias instead.

When you run a script the usual way, the current shell will create a new process for running the script, with a copy of the current shell's environment. The script will modify the copy, and then at the end of the script, that process will die and the modified environment will be lost.

Shell functions and aliases, on the other hand, are executed by the current shell, so they can easily modify the environment of the command line session.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example script:

```
$ cd ~/bin
$ cat example
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello
```

To run this, I could `source` it like in telcoM's answer:

```
$ source example
Hello
```

But instead, we are going to add executable permissions so it can be executed directly:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 stew stew 23 Feb 12 10:15 example
$ chmod +x example
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stew stew 23 Feb 12 10:15 example
```

Now we can call this script by referring to its absolute or relative path:

```
$ ./example
Hello
$ ~/bin/example
Hello
```

If you expect to rarely run this command, that's usually good enough. But if you'll be running this often, you may want to run the executable without specifying its location.

Normally, I would put this script in a place that `$PATH` already points to (i.e. `/usr/local/bin`).  That helps me stay organized as all of my custom scripts are in the same place and available to all users.

In some cases I like to have user-specific scripts in `$HOME/bin` and in that case, I need to add that directory to the `$PATH` environment variable.

We can temporarily append a directory to `PATH` for the current command:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ PATH=$PATH:~/bin example
Hello
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

This isn't so useful because we are still typing the path of the directory.  It's mostly useful for setting options via environment variable for a single execution.

If we want this to persist a little longer (perhaps we want to run the command several times in this shell session) we can set it for the shell:

```
$ PATH=$PATH:~/bin
$ example
Hello
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:~/bin
```

This is great if you're going to be using the command a bunch in the next 10 minutes, and then probably never again.  But this change will be lost when a new terminal is started.

Assuming you are using `bash`, we can make this change persist between sessions by automatically setting it when bash is started. The following command adds my directory to my user's `bashrc` which is run whenever a new instance of `bash` is launched:

```
$ echo 'PATH=$PATH:~/bin` >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now whenever I launch a new shell, I have that directory in my `PATH` and I can call `example` without specifying a path.  Note that this does not affect other users on the system.

```
$ example
Hello
```

---

In your specific question, your main mistake was not adding a colon `:` between the existing `$PATH` and your custom directory.